# How can use SQLBulkCopy on a table with a GUID primary key and default newsequentialid()?

Tags: .net, sql

When using SQLBulkCopy on a table with a GUID primary key and default newsequentialid()

e.g

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[MyPrimaryKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [MyConstraint]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
[Status] [int] NULL,
[Priority] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[MyPrimaryKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

wIth the C# code

```
        tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection,SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tran);            

        sqlCopy.DestinationTableName = "MyTable";            
        sqlCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

Gives you an error...

Column 'MyPrimaryKey' does not allow DBNull.Value

I've tried fiddling the the SqlBulkCopyOptions.  The only thing that works is setting the MyPrimaryKey field to allow nulls and removing the primary key.

Anyone know if there is a workaround for this issue?
Or can you verify that there is no workaround (other than changing the table structure)?

Answer (score 13):

You need to set up the column mappings. First call

```
sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
```

Then call

```
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Status", "Status");
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Priority", "Priority");
```

This means the bulk copy will stop trying to insert into MyPrimaryKey column and will only insert into the status and Priority columns.

Comment: JRummell, will the GUID column automatically generate a new value for each row inserted via the SQLBULKCOPY command? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're only options are to remove the MyPrimaryKey field from the data that is being loaded or to modify the table structure.

With the field being there with no values you are telling SQL that you want to force a null into the field, which, obviously, is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the database generated columns from the column set before writing is what you need to do.

We use LINQ-to-SQL for most of our database operations, but use another method for inserting many records at once, as L2S is a bit slow for this.

We have a generic method called `BulkInsertAll<>` that we can use on any table, which uses `SqlBulkCopy` internally. We dynamically generate the columns using reflection based on the generic type's properties. The `ColumnAttribute` is found in the .cs file generated from our .dbml file, where we have specified the guid primary key column as `IsDbGenerated="true"`.

```
public void BulkInsertAll<T>( IEnumerable<T> entities ) {
    entities = entities.ToArray();

    string cs = Connection.ConnectionString;
    var conn = new SqlConnection( cs );
    conn.Open();

    Type t = typeof( T );

    var tableAttribute = (TableAttribute) t.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof( TableAttribute ), false
    ).Single();

    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy( conn ) {
        DestinationTableName = tableAttribute.Name
    };

    var properties = t.GetProperties().Where( EventTypeFilter );

    // This will prevent the bulk insert from attempting to update DBGenerated columns
    // Without, inserts with a guid pk will fail to get the generated sequential id
    // If uninitialized guids are passed to the DB, it will throw duplicate key exceptions
    properties = properties.Where( 
        x => !x.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( ColumnAttribute ), false )
            .Cast<ColumnAttribute>().Any( attr => attr.IsDbGenerated )
    );

    var table = new DataTable();

    foreach( var property in properties ) {
        Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
        if( propertyType.IsGenericType &&
            propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( Nullable<> ) ) {
            propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType( propertyType );
        }

        table.Columns.Add( new DataColumn( property.Name, propertyType ) );
    }

    foreach( var entity in entities ) {
        table.Rows.Add( 
            properties.Select( 
                property => GetPropertyValue( property.GetValue( entity, null ) ) 
            ).ToArray()
        );
    }

    //specify the mapping for SqlBulk Upload
    foreach( var col in properties ) {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add( col.Name, col.Name );
    }

    bulkCopy.WriteToServer( table );

    conn.Close();
}


private bool EventTypeFilter( System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p ) {
    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute( p,
        typeof( AssociationAttribute ) ) as AssociationAttribute;

    if( attribute == null ) return true;
    if( attribute.IsForeignKey == false ) return true;

    return false;
}

private object GetPropertyValue( object o ) {
    if( o == null )
        return DBNull.Value;
    return o;
}
```

And this works just fine. The entities won't be updated with the newly assigned Guid, so you'll have to make another query to get those, but the new rows have property generated guids in the database.

We could wrap that `.Where` filter into the EventTypeFilter method, but I'm not the one who wrote most of this, and I haven't gone through it to tune everything up.